# My terminal hangs after promise.all resolves, why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Hi I am using Firebase for backend and I want to understand why this is just hanging in the terminal.

I am trying to seed my Authentication list and my Firestore db, so I created a seeding script. I read a list of users from a JSON file, and then I add them to Auth, however, in order to create a matching user record in Firestore, I retain the user ID that is returned to me from `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` to create a user object with first_name and last_name (trivial attributes).

Afterwards, I return that user object, and resolve all promises with `Promise.all` and then continue to use `setDoc` to add each of those user objects to Firestore.

*Note: both of these promise arrays are created using map functions across the initial user list from JSON and then across the returned user object list from Auth, respectively.*

The key point here is, even though everything is added to my Auth and Firestore just fine... the terminal stays hanging, to no avail...

```
const { store, auth } = require('../config.js');
const { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } = require('firebase/auth');
const { doc, setDoc } = require('firebase/firestore');

const data = require("./SEED_DATA.json");

console.log(data ? "DATA PRESENT" : "")

const seedUsers = async (users) => {
  // seeds firebase Auth
  const user_auth_hydrated = await Promise.all(users.map(user => {
    return createUserInAuth(user)
  }))

  // seeds firebase Firestore
  // we wait for auth because we want to retain the uids to create matching records in store
  const user_store = await Promise.all(user_auth_hydrated.map(user => {
    return createUserInStore(user)
  }))

  Promise.resolve(user_store)
}

const createUserInAuth = async ({first_name, last_name, email, password}) => {
  return await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // Signed in 
    const {uid} = userCredential.user;
    return {
      ID: uid.toString(),
      FIRSTNAME: first_name,
      LASTNAME: last_name
    }
  })
  .catch(err => console.log("USER ADD AUTH FAILED", err.code, err.message))
}

const createUserInStore = async ({ID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME}) => {
  return await setDoc(doc(store, 'users', ID), {FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME})
}

seedUsers(data);
```

Picture of terminal just hanging post execution (everything is fine in Auth and Firestore):
[image]

Comment: btw no need to "return await", if you return a promise, it should be awaited by wherever the function is called. As the function itself is async, thus a promise it's a bad practice to return await, just return the pending promise.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't mix traditional approach of promises and async / await syntax together. I advise to stick with async / await only.

The `seedUsers` async function returns undefined. Doing `Promise.resolve(user_store)` does nothing except creating an object that is destroyed at the end of the function.

You should fix your code as follows:

```js
const seedUsers = async (users) => {
  /* your logic */
  return user_store;
}
```

and

```js
const createUserInAuth = async ({first_name, last_name, email, password}) => {
  try {
    const userCredential = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    /* your return logic */
  } catch (error) {
    /* your error logic */
  }
}
```